# replace substring with and without comma

Tags: php, mysql

`cnt` is  a text column like this:

```
lorem,ipsum,sky,dolor
lorem,sky,ipsum
lorem,ipsum,dolor,sky
```

I want to remove `sky` from entire column

```
$sq = "update table set cnt = replace(cnt, :a, :b)";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute([
        ":a" => 'sky'
        ":b" => ''
    ]);
```

Problem
`sky` sometimes has a commma  - it should be removed also
and sometimes is without comma (at the end of string)

How to remove `sky` with **and** without comma?

Comment: Use on the cnt string [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string into an array, then you can search for the value you want to remove (for example by using [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)). And finally make it a string again with [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$sq = "update table set cnt = replace(cnt, :a, '')";
$st = $db->prepare($sq);
$st->execute([":a" => $a . ',']);
$st->execute([":a" => $a]);
```

Comment: Will give wrong output if entered value is a substring of another value (replace 'abc' in 'xabcd').

Comment: your guess is not part of my case. It is clear from the question that these are csv values. And don’t be so vain. This is a much simpler solution and works perfectly

Comment: *It is clear from the question that these are csv values.* And you guarantee that none CVS vaue is a substring of another CSV value? If so then why this fact is skipped in the question?

Comment: Here is the first sentence of my question: `cnt is a text column like this`. So - `like this` - means - `like this`

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE test
SET cnt = TRIM( BOTH ',' 
                FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', cnt, ','), 
                                     CONCAT(',', @a, ','), 
                                     CONCAT(',', @b, ',')),
                             ',,',
                             ','));
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a85bd78ad9ab354cbbfaef0fa4cd0a9f)

Comment: maybe simpler - one query to replace and a second one for trim both

Comment: Yes, at least three requests... at least four... but what's the point?